What are the numbers and thumbsup in the post chapter screen?
When you complete a chapter you get a summary screen, showing you what rewards you've earned.
At the top are the characters you used, with some numbers and one has a thumbs up icon.

What are the numbers telling me and what's the thumbs up for?

Only going to comment because I'm guessing, but I assumed the top numbers are total damage, with the golden thumbs-up meaning MVP/most damage. The 10s are probably character level. This is based off my experiences of ~6 hours playing the game.
